# Quickbooks PHP SDK different actions it can perform

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QB Php sdk from last 7 years and it is working fine with stability.

I request Keith from consolybyte & other fellow members to please share the list of all allowed actions which can be done in QB Desktop via QB PHP SDK. I have been using invoice, item, payments, customer (add/mod/del) actions.

I want to know what else can be done via PHP SDK. In Quickbooks.php alot of functions are mentioned but not sure if all of these are supported for QB Desktop. It will be of great help if exact list can be provided. There is no proper documentation of same. I have gone through. At couple of places(https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) it is mentioned it supports order push from website to QB and etc etc. I am looking for exact "etc" list :) Thank you for the assistance in advance

Answer (score 0):

All of what QuickBooks desktop supports is documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop